# Adding a condition to a process flow in SAS

Tags: conditional-statements, sas

I know I can add a condition to a query. Can I add a condition to a process flow? I have 5 process flow in my project. Some process is not supposed to run if certain condition is not met. There are 20 queries in the process flow. I don't want to add the same condition 20 times. I want to add it to the process flow level. Is this possible?

Comment: EG/Studio/Viya? What SAS application are you using?

Comment: Could also be DI Studio or Event Manager. In all these five SAS projects "process flow" has a slightly different meaning. So, be more specific Azuki !